# Hash indexing - do they support range look up

Tags: indexing, hash

I had a question about hash indexing in database design. Do they support range lookup? if not why?
Thank you

Comment: Can you add some details to your question? Do you mean hash indexing in a database or some kind of programming framework?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean hash indexing in database

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? Or do you have an actual database system in mind? I think order-preserving hash-functions are uncommon for standard databases, but there are hash functions like [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) which generates related hashes to related inputs.

Comment: well to be honest this is part of a lecture note that I could n't brain storm and understand. I mean I couldn't grasp why in a hash indexed data base structure we can't do range look up? one thing came to my mind is that since hashed search keys are not sorted in the directory array then range search is not possible. But I am not sure my reasoning is correct

Comment: Keep thinking about it and read how a hashtable works opposed to a tree like datastrucure - you're on the right way!